# Why isn't the markdown created table displaying correctly

Tags: bug, markdown

When I addded this autoconverted table in Edit- it shows correctly but in the final post it is all messed up- how to create mark down table so it works?

| Stage | Startup | Pre-action (~1s) | Action | Attacker Communicates move to pet | OpportunityWindow 1 | Attacker Pet attacks Defender Opportunity 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Defen-der (AI) | No move | Can move (but often doesn't) | Can move (moves if Attacker doesn't straight away) | Communication will confuse pet with no action | Can set a move | Can't set a move but can set a direction |
| Attack-er | No move | No move | Can move (assume he communicates a move) Choose commands and hit enter | Now communcate to pet with specific location directions by mouse for directed attack | Pet is preparing- Communication would confuse it | Pet completes move with resolution can miss |

Comment: The table looks correct on my browser. Can you provide a screenshot of what you're seeing, or describe in more detail what makes it "all messed up"? It may also help to detail what browser and OS you're using, in case the issue is specific to your software environment.

Comment: When I first did it, it didn't show any text in the proper post. The Mod edited the post and somehow it came out right.

Comment: I noticed you had some extra ``` ``` at the end of your post you didn't need, so I removed those, but it still displayed correctly for me even with those in place.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is documented in [this bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357596/674198) on meta.se, I'll reproduce the entire answer below for reference. You will notice in the answer below that the last markdown table renders as `text above table |test|test| |----|----| |test|test|` when viewing this post, but if you pull up the post preview by clicking "Edit", the preview renderer will replace the unparsed text with a preview of the mardown table.

---

If you have text right above or below the table, the preview renders the table markdown as a table. But after you save the post, the table is not rendered and just shows the markdown code.

You can use the code below as an example. If you try to edit my answer, it shows a table in the preview but not in the backend-rendered post view.

#### Raw Markdown:

```
text above table
|test|test|
|----|----|
|test|test|
```

#### How it looks in Preview

[image: Table formatted correctly]

#### Result after posting

text above table
|test|test|
|----|----|
|test|test|

So either the backend renderer is broken or the preview renderer is broken.

---